# Stripe payment via PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the payment code example found here for Stripe in PHP:

https://gist.github.com/boucher/1750375

I have this setup, but whenever I click the "Submit Payment" button I get an error :

Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in /xxxx/stripe.php on line 7

I am using the following include, which seems to be meant to load all the Stripe API files:

```
require_once('stripe-php-2.1.2/init.php');
```

I have verified that this file exists and it's pointing to the correct directory on the server where I have placed the Stripe API files.

Comment: You might have to load the class via its namespace. Something like \Stripe\Stripe.

Comment: @Stuart Wagner  yes it appears that is the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1110562 I'm glad you got it to work. Would you mind answering your own question so that others that find this post can easily see how you solved your issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the class via its namespace.

```
\Stripe\Stripe
```

Thanks to Stuart Wagner for the answer!